# Sources for summation topics

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on the combinatorics topics. I'm trying to look for some summation related sources such as exchanging the order in multiple summations and summation of combinations. My textbook doesn't explain these stuffs. Can someone recommend some sources except wiki?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this qualifies as an answer for you. I've done (on my amateur level) many small investigations of such summations; one of them (Stirlingnumbers & Bellnumbers) went so far that it was -in my view- interesting enough for a small article.
In case you'll receive no other references for more elaborate/standard examples you might be interested in this  ["Summing of Stirling & Bellnumbers"](http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial/04_5_SummingBellStirling.pdf) At page 12&13 is the core argument for a (divergent) summation process of the Bellnumbers which may give an idea how to proceed in similar cases.